# Adding a paragraph in a file from python

Tags: python, append

I am appending a file via python based on the code that has been input by the user.

```
with open ("markbook.txt", "a") as g:
        g.write(sn+","+sna+","+sg1+","+sg2+","+sg3+","+sg4)
```

`sn`, `sna`, `sg1`, `sg2`, `sg3`, `sg4` have all been entered by the user and when the program is finished a line will be added to the `'markbook.txt'` file in the format of:

```
00,SmithJE,a,b,b,b
01,JonesFJ,e,d,c,d
02,BlairJA,c,c,b,a
03,BirchFA,a,a,b,c
```

The issue is when the program is used again and the file is appended further, the new line is simply put on the end of the previous line. How do I place the appended text below the previous line?

Answer (score 1):

Add a "\n" to the end of the write line.

So:

```
g.write(sn+","+sna+","+sg1+","+sg2+","+sg3+","+sg4+"\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write line separators between your your lines:

```
g.write(sn + "," + sna + "," + sg1 + "," + sg2 + "," + sg3 + "," + sg4 + '\n')
```

You appear to be reinventing the CSV wheel, however. Leave separators (line or column) to the [`csv` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) instead:

```
import csv

with open ("markbook.txt", "ab") as g:
    writer = csv.writer(g)
    writer.writerow([sn, sna, sg1, sg2, sg3, sg4])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the new line character at the end of your string. Also, though string concatenation is completely fine in this case, you should be aware that Python has alternative options for formatting strings.

```
    with open('markbook.txt', 'a') as g:
        g.write('{},{},{},{},{},{}\n'
               .format(sn, sna, sg1, sg2, sg3, sg4))
```